# switch text on click python pygame wih a function's button

Tags: python, click, pygame

I am trying to make a game/quiz with python 2.7 and pygame and I want the user to click the button with the correct answer. I have made a button function that checks if the mouse is inside the button and proceed to an action. The problem is that when I run the program after I click start, it shows the second screen instead of the fist one.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 900
display_height = 600

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (250,0,0)
green = (0,250,0)
bright_red =(200,0,0)
bright_green = (0,200,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("A MATH'S GAME")


def button(msg,x,y,w,h,ic,ac,action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    if x+w > mouse[0] > x and y+h > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ac,(x,y,w,h))

        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            action()         
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(gameDisplay, ic,(x,y,w,h))

    smallText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",20)
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg, smallText)
    textRect.center = ( (x+(w/2)), (y+(h/2)) )
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def messgae_display(text):
    largeText = pygame.font.Font("Arial",60)
    TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects(text, largeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

    pygame.display.update()

    game_loop()

def quitgame():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def game_intro():

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",115)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("A math's game", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2),(display_height/2))
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button("GO!",150,450,100,50,green,bright_green,game_loop)
        button("Quit",550,450,100,50,red,bright_red,quitgame)

        pygame.display.update()

def game_loop():

    gameExit = False

    while not gameExit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",48)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("A math's game", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), 100)
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",48)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Pick a choice", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), 200)
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",48)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("1 QUESTION", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), 280)
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button1 = button("Option1",120,350,300,150,red,bright_red,option1_loop)
        button2 = button("Option2",520,350,300,150,red,bright_red,None)

        pygame.display.update()

def option1_loop():


    option1Exit = False

    while not option1Exit:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",48)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("A math's game", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), 100)
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",48)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("Pick a choice", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), 200)
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)
        largeText = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",48)
        TextSurf, TextRect = text_objects("2 QUESTION", largeText)
        TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), 280)
        gameDisplay.blit(TextSurf, TextRect)

        button1 = button("Option1.1",120,350,300,150,red,bright_red,None)
        button2 = button("Option2.1",520,350,300,150,red,bright_red,None)

       pygame.display.update()


game_intro()
game_loop()
option1_loop()
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: you can render text before `while` loop and only blit text in `while` loop.

Comment: inside `game_intro()` you run `game_loop()` so there is no sense to put `game_loop()` below `game_intro()` (at the end of code) - it will be newer executed.

Comment: problem can be `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` which return true all the time when you keep pressed button, and because computer is faster than you. When you click button then it changes to first screen but button on first screen see that you still keep button pressed so it changes to second screen. `event.type = pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` could be better because it send event only once - when button change state from non-pressed to pressed.

Comment: problem is that your `button()` function do two things - it check mouse and it draw it - so can't be use easily with `event.type = pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is because you use `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()` which is `True` all the time when you keep pressed. When you press on first screen then it change to second screen which see that button is pressed and it automatically click button and change to third screen.

You could use `event.type = pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` which is executed only once - when button change state from non-pressed to pressed. But you have to split your `button()` into `button_check()` and `button_draw()`

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

DISPLAY_WIDTH  = 900
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 600

BLACK = (  0,  0,  0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
RED   = (250,  0,  0)
GREEN = (  0,250,  0)
BRIGHT_RED   = (200,  0,  0)
BRIGHT_GREEN = (  0,200,  0)

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

# empty

# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

def button_check(button):

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    if button['rect'].collidepoint(mouse):
        if click[0] == 1 and button['action']:
            button['action']()         


def button_draw(button):
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 20)

    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    if button['rect'].collidepoint(mouse):
        color = button['ac']
    else:
        color = button['ic']

    pygame.draw.rect(game_display, color, button['rect'])

    image, rect = text_objects(button['msg'], font)
    rect.center = button['rect'].center
    game_display.blit(image, rect)

def text_objects(text, font):
    image = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    rect  = image.get_rect()
    return image, rect

def message_display(text):
    font = pygame.font.Font("Arial" ,60)

    image, rect = text_objects(text, font)
    rect.center = game_display_rect.center
    game_display.blit(image, rect)

    pygame.display.update()

def quit_game():
    pygame.quit()
    quit()

def game_intro():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 115)

    game_display.fill(WHITE)

    image, rect = text_objects("A math's game", font)
    rect.center = game_display_rect.center
    game_display.blit(image, rect)

    buttons = [
        {
            'msg': 'GO!',
            'rect': pygame.Rect(150, 450, 100, 50),
            'ac': GREEN, 
            'ic': BRIGHT_GREEN,
            'action': game_loop,
        },
        {
            'msg': 'Quit',
            'rect': pygame.Rect(550, 450, 100, 50),
            'ac': RED,   
            'ic': BRIGHT_RED,
            'action': game_loop
        }
    ]

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit_game()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                button_check(buttons[0])
                button_check(buttons[1])

        button_draw(buttons[0])
        button_draw(buttons[1])

        pygame.display.update()

def game_loop():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",48)

    game_display.fill(WHITE)

    image, rect = text_objects("A math's game", font)
    rect.center = (game_display_rect.centerx, 100)
    game_display.blit(image, rect)

    image, rect = text_objects("Pick a choice", font)
    rect.center = (game_display_rect.centerx, 200)
    game_display.blit(image, rect)

    image, rect = text_objects("1 QUESTION", font)
    rect.center = (game_display_rect.centerx, 280)
    game_display.blit(image, rect)

    buttons = [
        {
            'msg': 'Option1',
            'rect': pygame.Rect(120, 350, 300, 150),
            'ac': RED, 
            'ic': BRIGHT_RED,
            'action': option1_loop,
        },
        {
            'msg': 'Option2',
            'rect': pygame.Rect(520, 350, 300, 150),
            'ac': RED,   
            'ic': BRIGHT_RED,
            'action': None
        }
    ]

    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit_game()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                button_check(buttons[0])
                button_check(buttons[1])

        button_draw(buttons[0])
        button_draw(buttons[1])

        pygame.display.update()

def option1_loop():
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms",48)

    game_display.fill(WHITE)

    image, rect = text_objects("A math's game", font)
    rect.center = (game_display_rect.centerx, 100)
    game_display.blit(image, rect)

    image, rect = text_objects("Pick a choice", font)
    rect.center = (game_display_rect.centerx, 200)
    game_display.blit(image, rect)

    image, rect = text_objects("2 QUESTION", font)
    rect.center = (game_display_rect.centerx, 280)
    game_display.blit(image, rect)

    buttons = [
        {
            'msg': 'Option1.1',
            'rect': pygame.Rect(120, 350, 300, 150),
            'ac': RED, 
            'ic': BRIGHT_RED,
            'action': option1_loop,
        },
        {
            'msg': 'Option2.1',
            'rect': pygame.Rect(520, 350, 300, 150),
            'ac': RED,   
            'ic': BRIGHT_RED,
            'action': None
        }
    ]

    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quit_game()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                button_check(buttons[0])
                button_check(buttons[1])

        button_draw(buttons[0])
        button_draw(buttons[1])

        pygame.display.update()

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
game_display_rect = game_display.get_rect()

pygame.display.set_caption("A MATH'S GAME")

game_intro()
```